# How can a terminal know it is running in vscode?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I want to have different settings in the vscode's terminal and the standalone terminal, is there a way to tell the terminal itself that if it is running in vscode or standalone?

Comment: Maybe you can check if `TERM_PROGRAM` environment variable is set to `vscode` value.

Comment: this is exactly what environment vars are for, provided you are in a position to query them prior to taking an action.